# Job steps sum'ed by a job name

Tags: sql-server, jobs

I am trying to write a query to return the sum of all the job steps of a specific job.

Problem #1: is if the same job ran more than once a day it now groups two or more RUNS together giving incorrect SUM.

Problem #2:  If the job runs late in the day and some steps run after midnight they end up grouped with the wrong next day's job run.

Any help in solving this one is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I can't post a small table of data from XL so I am gong to explain the scenario: Specific job has some steps and 1st run the steps ran late in the day with the last step running after midnight (Hence job started one day and finished the next day).  2nd run, ran in the morning.  3rd run, ran the same day as the 2nd run.
Now when grouping by Start date to get the  sum of all the steps this gets messy.